# access environment variable in React-Native AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to React Native. The task at hand is to set my Google API key in AndroidManifest.xml without exposing it, when pushed to GitHub.
I set up **an environment variable** called API_KEY, but however I want to **access it in the .xml**, I get an error when trying to spin up the dev server.

So far I tried:

```
android:value=${env.API_KEY}
android:value="${env.API_KEY}"
android:value="${API_KEY}"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

assuming that you have defined the key in your .env file, you can set that up on `build.gradle` as `manifestPlaceholders`.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [API_KEY: "$process.env.your_key"]
    }
    ...
}
```

on your `AndroidManifest.xml`,

```
android:value="${API_KEY}"
```

Comment: If I understand it right, now the key is in an other .gradle, still exposed in my repo. It should be nice to access environment variable instead.

Comment: hey @kenmistry, I am working with react and I am reading several env files via:project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
    release: ".env.prod",
    debug: ".env.dev",
    staging: ".env.stage"]
- can I also read it from there? Somehow it tells me the value is "null" when I try.

Comment: @Fapi , how did you call it? like this - `$process.env.prod.your_key`

Comment: I think I tried like this and also with $System

Comment: i think you should declare the `prod`,  `dev` and `stage` variables within a single `env` file and use named variables like this `API_KEY_FOR_PROD` or `API_KEY_FOR_STAGE`.

Comment: note that there are more than one build.gradle files, this change should be done in `android/app/build.gradle`

Answer (score 13):

Based on the second comment (from kenmistry), the solution that worked for me was indeed to create a placeholder in build.gradle, but since, for whatever reason, configuring and referring a .env  file did't work, I invoked my environment variables like so in build.gradle:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [API_KEY: "$System.env.API_KEY"]
```

and accessed it in the .xml as suggested by kenmistry:

```
android:value="${API_KEY}"
```

Comment: This works for me. I tried the accepted answer first, but `$process.env.API_KEY` threw an error `Could not get unknown property 'process'`.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that the above solutions aren't working for, I had to use this syntax in `android/app/build.gradle` under the `android.defaultConfig` section:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [MY_ENV_VAR:"${System.getenv("MY_ENV_VAR")}"]
```

and then in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` under the `<manifest><application>` section

```
<meta-data android:name="myEnvVar" android:value="${MY_ENV_VAR}" />
```